# How to redirect Valgrind's output to a file?

Tags: redirect, valgrind

While working with Valgrind tool, i need to log the details produced by valgrind tool. How can I accomplish that? I tried something like,

```
 valgrind a.out | test
```

and

```
 valgrind a.out > test
```

It gave just the program's output and not the valgrind memory error,leak information. Even i am getting like this if the program requires no user interaction (i.e. giving input). If the program need user input even that thing itself won't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried redirecting both stout and stderr?
`valgrind a.out &> file`

Answer (score 459, accepted):

```
valgrind --log-file="filename"
```

Comment: this saves just stderr, is it possible to save both stderr and stdout into same file in the same order as is written in terminal ( i.e. to keep coherence between outputs of tested program and error reported by valgrind) ?

Answer (score 92):

By default, Valgrind writes its output to stderr.  So you need to do something like:

```
valgrind a.out > log.txt 2>&1
```

Alternatively, you can tell Valgrind to write somewhere else; see http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.comment (but I've never tried this).

Comment: Thanks a lot :). It worked. Can you please tell me what's with that "2>&1"?

Comment: @Dinesh: I suggest reading http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections, which describes the bizarre Bash syntax for doing redirections!

Comment: NOTE: that this suggestion will also send `a.out`'s output to the same log file.  If you want to save valgrind's output to the logfile *without* `a.out`'s, you should use the `--log-file` option suggested by Lex.

Comment: This is also a great answer for debugging memory leaks!

Comment: If you want to pipe output to another command: `valgrind ./struct -v --leak-check=full 2>&1 | nc -N paste.ubuntu.ir 1337`

Answer (score 12):

You can also set the options --log-fd if you just want to read your logs with a less.
For example :

```
valgrind --log-fd=1 ls | less
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answers (particularly by [Lekakis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12420689/3393574)), some string replacements can also be used in the option `--log-file=` as elaborated in the [Valgrind's user manual](https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.basicopts).

Four replacements were available at the time of writing:

- `%p`: Prints the current process ID

  - `valgrind --log-file="myFile-%p.dat" <application-name>`
- `%n`: Prints file sequence number unique for the current process

  - `valgrind --log-file="myFile-%p-%n.dat" <application-name>`
- `%q{ENV}`: Prints contents of the environment variable `ENV`

  - `valgrind --log-file="myFile-%q{HOME}.dat" <application-name>`
- `%%`: Prints `%`

  - `valgrind --log-file="myFile-%%.dat" <application-name>`