# How to redirect the output of the program Valgrind is running on?

Tags: bash, valgrind

#### Background of the question:

I run a command like this:

```
$ valgrind ./my_program < 1.in
```

And I get Valgrind's messages about leaks and errors as well as the output stdout and stderr streams of the my_program.

### Question:

I would like to redirect/mute all the streams of my_program (both stdout and stderr).

#### Where's what I've learnt so far:

- Running `> /dev/null` doesn't mute the stderr stream of my_program.
- Running `> /dev/null 2> /dev/null` mutes all the output stream of my_program all together with Valgrind's messages.
- According to this thread: [How to redirect Valgrind's output to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355979/how-to-redirect-valgrinds-output-to-a-file) Valgrind is capable of streaming its output directly to a log file using `valgrind --log-file="filename"`.

#### Possible solution:

I've came up with a solution like this

```
$ valgrind --log-file="filename" ./my_program < 1.in && cat filename
```

**Is there an easier way to do this?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To separate valgrind and application output you can redirect valgrind output to another file descriptor:
`valgrind --log-fd=9 9>>test.log ./app`

Comment: Could you possibly explain what your command does? I thought I could just find something about `--log-fd` but there is nothing like this in the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski --log-fd is a valgrind option. It tells valgrind to output valgrind stuff into specified file descriptor. I guess the rest should be clear.

Comment: I've managed to write what I wanted thanks to your help: `valgrind --log-fd=9 ./app  < test.in 1>/dev/null`. This solution prints Valgrind's messages and hides app's output.

Answer (score 6):

This may be a little late to the punch, but I'm running valgrind 3.10.1 on ubuntu, and you can simply use the `--log-file=<filename>` flag.
I.E. run:

```
valgrind [args] --log-file=<filename> ./my_program
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood the question, this is the answer that I found works for me:

```
valgrind --log-fd=9 [program]  9>&1 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

This outputs the valgrind messages to stdout, but the stdout and stderr from the program goes to /dev/null. The order of the redirects is important, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12027221/300213).

A "-q" option will also restrict valgrind to errors only.